# Record Limit for sfdx force:data:tree:import plan?

Tags: salesforcedx

For SFDX tree imports executed using a plan, is the 200 record limit for all files included in the plan, or per file?  If I exported a nested query that had 20 parent records, and 199 child records, would I be over the 200 record import limitation, or since each file is < 200 records, would I be OK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have as many records as you'd like, but each file must be no more than 200 records. This command is essentially a wrapper for the [sobject tree API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobject_tree.htm). The data export command should correctly break up your file in to a number of records appropriate for an import when you use the `--plan` option.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you.

Comment: It appears that `sfdx force:data:export -p` does break up export files into multiple files (1 per object type), but it does not break up those individual files into batches of 200.  Looks like that has to be done manually.

Comment: @Brian Hmm, I've never tested it with larger exports, but I guess it makes sense. The docs are kind of unclear about that feature. Still, at least the import can consist of as many files as you'd like so long as you keep the per-file limit under 200.

Comment: Yeah, the documentation could definitely be better on that front.  It would even be nice if there was a flag on the export to automatically do the splitting.